# How to make strings with the same value equal after loading from json file

Tags: python, json

Before I save to a .json file the string from the dictionary will equal a normal string but after I save and then load from that file the value from the dictionary will not be considered equal.  I have tested with integer values and those do work but the strings will not for me.  How do I make them equal each other?

Code:

```
import json

details = {'apple': 2, 'orange': 3, 'cat': 'tree'}
print("details['cat'] is 'tree':", details['cat'] is 'tree')

with open("example.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(details, outfile)
    outfile.close()

with open("example.json") as json_file:
    loaded_details = json.load(json_file)
    json_file.close()

print("loaded_details['cat'] is 'tree':", loaded_details['cat'] is 'tree')
```

Output:

```
details['cat'] is 'tree': True
loaded_details['cat'] is 'tree': False
```

Comment: if you want to compare two strings for equal value you should use '==' instead of 'is'.

Comment: You are not comparing the values with `is`, you are comparing object references...which is not the same thing and by which you get `False`